# How to consume authenticated RSS Feeds in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, rss, syndication-feed

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and the application is currently using Microsoft Azure ACS for authentication.

I know how to create the RSS Feeds using Syndication APIs (more info here - http://www.developerzen.com/2009/01/11/aspnet-mvc-rss-feed-action-result/) in MVC 4 but I am wondering how users will be able to consume the feed, as the authentication layer is coming in between the feed reader and the feed generator(controller).

Does anyone know how to consume such authenticated and personalized RSS Feeds or is there any other way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to return that feed with your application or to consume some third party feed from a website which requires authorization? Hence the question isn't completely clear, I'll try to answer.

In the fist case there is nothing extraordinary, just implement your controller's action which returns RSS with an `[Authorize]` attribute. For the second case you need to configure your `HttpWebRequest` class to send authentication headers. But for more extended explanations please clarify your initial question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
The MVC application which is returning the feed itself is authenticated by ACS.